# Compile libupnp on windows

Tags: c++, upnp

I'm trying to compile libupnp-1.6.17 on windows with VS2008, but hundreds syntax errors occured. I download source code from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pupnp/
 anyone tell me how to compile libupnp on windows?

Comment: Did you open the solution from the build/vc9 directory? What compile errors do you get?

Comment: OK,a stupid mistake, now I compiled it successfully, but when executing,it shows missing pthreadVC2.dll, then I copy it from pthreads folder, still error: Unable to locate the procedure entry point inet_pton on WS2_32.dll

Comment: inet_pton needs at least Windows Vista/Server 2008. What OS do you have (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ?

Comment: XP, do you mean libupnp do not support windows XP?

Comment: correct. Time to upgrade :)

Comment: Try http://sourceforge.net/projects/platinum/ if you are looking for UPnP library XP compatible

Answer (score 1):

WINDOWS BUILD

In order to build libupnp under Windows the pthreads-w32 package is required.
You can download a self-extracting ZIP file from the following location:

ftp://sources.redhat.com/pub/pthreads-win32/pthreads-w32-2-7-0-release.exe
or possibly newer versions if available.

Execute the self-extracting archive and copy the Pre-build.2 folder to the
top level source folder.
Rename Pre-build.2 to pthreads. 
Open the provided workspace build\libupnp.dsw with Visual C++ 6.0 and select
Build->Build libupnp.dll (F7)
In the build directory there are also VC8, VC9 and VC10 folders containing
solution files for Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010 respectively.

If you use newer versions to build libupnp, eg Visual Studio 2003 or later,
then you need to rebuild the pthreads package so it uses the same VC runtime
as libupnp to prevent cross boundary runtime problems
(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).
Just replace the files in the Pre-build.2 folder (renamed to pthreads as
mentioned above) with the newly build versions.
If you also use a newer version of pthreads-win32 then you should also
replace the header files in that directory structure (obviously).

For building a static library instead of a DLL and for using the static
pthreads-w32 library following switches need to be defined additionally:

UPNP_STATIC_LIB - for creating a statically linkable UPnP-library
PTW32_STATIC_LIB - for using the static pthreads32 library